# Finding the sum of the first term and common difference when given sum of first 5 and sum of first 10

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

the sum of the first 5 terms of an arithmetic series is 110 and the sum of the first 10 terms is 320. How do i go about finding the first term and common difference.

Sn  = n/2 [2a+d(n−1)] is the equation for working out the sum of an arithmetic series, but how can i rearrange to find for the first term and common difference. I belive it would be using simulatenous equations.

Comment: Hint: Plug in the values you have and you'll get $2$ linear equations in $2$ unknowns. Do you think you can solve that?

Comment: I am confused by what you mean. Would it be like

110=n/2 (2(a)+d(5-1)

Comment: In the equation you provided, $a$ is the first term, $d$ is the common difference and $n$ is the number of terms.

Comment: I understand that. How do I implement that into this question

Comment: Use your formula to set the sum of the first $5$ and $10$ terms to $110$ and $320$, respectively

Comment: Would it be like:
 110=n/2 (2(a)+d(5-1)
320= n/2 (2(a)+d(10-1)

Comment: Yes, and plug in the known values for $n$

Comment: @BND In the first one, $n = 5$ and in the second one $n = 10$, which I see you did for the second use of $n$ in the equation, but not the first use.

Comment: Once I do that I get
320= 5(2a+9d);
110=2.5(2a+4d)

What do i do from here, do i divide both sides?

Comment: Do you know how to solve two linear equations in two unknowns?

Comment: I do know. i just worked it out. Please correct me if am I wrong:
64=2a+9d  (1)
44=2a+4d  (2)

20=5d
4=d

sub d in (1) = 64=2a+9(4)
28=2a
a=14

Thus a=14 and d=4

Comment: That answer is correct.  You could post the answer

Comment: @BND Once you think you have a solution, substituting the values back into the original equations to ensure they still hold is a good way to help ensure you didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks guys. That has made a lot more sense to me and i can now solve the other questions. You guys are the best.

Answer (score 1):

Sn = n/2 (2a + (n-1) d)

110 = 5/2 (2a+(5–1)d) (Eq. 1)

320=10/2(2a+(10–1)d (Eq.2)

110=2.5(2a+5d-1d) - 110=2.5(2a+4d) (Eq.3)

320=5(2a+10d-1d) - 320=5(2a+9d) (Eq.4)

64=(2a+9d) - Divided both sides 5 from equation 4 (eq.5)

44=2a+4d - Divided both sides 2.5 from equation 3 (eq.6)

20=5d  - Simulataneous Equations - just minus it through. 64–44 is 20. 2a-2a is 0 and  9d-4d is 5d

4=d -20/5 is 4

Sub d into equation (5)

64 = 2a+9(4)

64=2a+36

28=2a

14=a

Therefore the first term would be 14 and the common difference would be 4

Answer (score 0):

Let first term $a_1$ be A (for ease of writing):
$$s_n=\frac{n}{2}[2A+(n-1)d]$$

Since $S_5=110$
$$s_5=110=\frac{5}{2}[2A+(5-1)d]$$
$$44=2A+4d \tag1$$

Since $S_{10}=320$
$$s_{10}=320=\frac{10}{2}[2A+(10-1)d]$$
$$64=2A+9d\tag2$$

Solving (1) and (2), We get:

$$d=4$$

Using either (1) or (2), say (1), we substitute $d=4$ to get $A$:

$$44=2A+4(4)$$

Solving for $A$, we get $$A=14$$

The series is:
$$14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, ...$$

Note: [Arithmatic Progression-Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) has a good list of formulae related to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}{c| cccccccccccccc}
\text{index} & 1 & 2    & 3     &  4    & 5\\
\text{term}  & a & a+d  &  a+2d &  a+3d & a+4d \\
\text{sum}   & a & 2a+d & 3a+3d & 4a+6d & \color{red}{5a+10d=110} \\
\text{formula} &&&&& 5\dfrac{(a)+(a+4d)}{2}
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c| cccccccccccccc}
\text{index} & 6      & 7      & 8      &  9     & 10\\
\text{term}  &  a+ 5d &  a+ 6d &  a+ 7d &  a+ 8d & a+9d \\
\text{sum}   & 6a+15d & 7a+21d & 8a+28d & 9a+36d & \color{red}{10a+45d=320}\\
\text{formula} &&&&& 10\dfrac{(a)+(a+9d)}{2}
\end{array}$

\begin{align}
    5a+10d &=110 \\
   10a+45d &=320 \\
\hline
    10a+20d &=220 \\
   10a+45d &=320 \\
\hline
   25d &= 100 \\
\hline
   d &= 4 \\
   a &= 14
\end{align}